# Adding values from multiple dictionaries that will create a final total receipt

Tags: python, dictionary

So I'm attempting to add values from four dictionaries, after user input (this program requires different types of things in a store, so I created four dictionaries for four types of things), and I'm at the point where I want to create a final total, but I'm a bit stumped regarding how to add whatever has been ordered from (potentially) all four dictionaries. Included in this has to be sales tax, but I'm not particularly worried about that issue.

```
drinks_list = []
drinks_list = sorted(drinks_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1], reverse = True)
if drinks_list:
    print("Drinks")
    for item in drinks_list:
        if item[1][2] > 0:
            print("Selection: %s, Cost: %.2f, Ordered: %i "%(item[1][0], item[1][1], item[1][2]))

salads_list = []
salads_list = sorted(salads_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1], reverse = True)
if salads_list:
    print("Salads")
    for item in salads_list:
        if item[1][2] > 0:
            print("Selection: %s;;; Cost:%.2f;;; OrderCount:%i "%(item[1][0], item[1][1], item[1][2]))

sandwiches_list = []
sandwiches_list = sorted(sandwiches_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1], reverse = True)
if sandwiches_list:
    print("Sandwiches")
    for item in sandwiches_list:
        if item[1][2] > 0:
            print("Selection: %s;;; Cost:%.2f;;; OrderCount:%i "%(item[1][0], item[1][1], item[1][2]))

desserts_list = []
desserts_list = sorted(desserts_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1], reverse = True)
if desserts_list:
    print("Desserts")
    for item in desserts_list:
        if item[1][2] > 0:
            print("Selection: %s;;; Cost:%.2f;;; OrderCount:%i "%(item[1][0], item[1][1], item[1][2]))
```

Only part of the full program code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
def add_up(items, name):
    items_list = sorted(items.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1], reverse = True)
    if items_list:
    print(name)
    for item in items_list:
        if item[1][2] > 0:
            print("Selection: %s, Cost: %.2f, Ordered: %i "%(item[1][0], item[1][1], item[1][2]))
            return item[1][1]*item[1][2]

total = 0
order = {'Drinks':drinks_dict, 'Salads':salads_dict, 'Sandiwches':sandwiches_dict, 'Desserts':desserts_dict]
for o in order:
    total += add_up(order[o], o)

print "Total cost = %.2f" % total
```